# How to achieve const-correctness in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, const-correctness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“const correctness” in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114149/const-correctness-in-c-sharp)

I have programmed C++ for many years but am fairly new to C#. While learning C# I found that the use of the [const](http://en.csharp-online.net/const,_static_and_readonly) keyword is much more limited than in C++. AFAIK, there is, [for example](http://andymcm.com/csharpfaq.htm#6.8), no way to declare arguments to a function const. I feel uncomfortable with the idea that I may make inadvertent changes to my function arguments (which may be complex data structures) that I can only detect by testing.

How do you deal with this situation?

Comment: It was also answered recently on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114149/const-correctness-in-c

Comment: Andreas--I misread the question.  I've removed my reply since I referenced C++ which is not what you were asking.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent blog post about this issue by Stan Lippman: [A question of const](http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/01/22/61712.aspx)

Comment: This posting is about C++/CLI, not C#

Comment: It's an explanation why it's not there at all.  In any .NET language.

Answer (score 2):

If it matters, I use immutable objects.  Or, at a minimum, I use the logic in my property setters.