# Does c#'s ref copy and how to prevent it?

Tags: c#, ref

In c++ passing a const reference is often used to save time copying. I know that c# has a `ref` keyword, but the accepted answer in [How do I pass a const reference in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385224/how-do-i-pass-a-const-reference-in-c) says that it still creates a copy of the passed variable, but modifies them both. How can I prevent that?

Comment: What you wrote is not correct. See here about the ref keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Comment: You've "heard something", you can try making a short program to test that out to see if it's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ref` keyword is used to pass an argument by reference, not value. The `ref` keyword makes the formal parameter alias for the argument, which must be a variable. In other words, any operation on the parameter is made on the argument.

For example:

```
void Method(ref int refArgument)
{
    refArgument = refArgument + 44;
}

int number = 1;
Method(ref number);
Console.WriteLine(number);
// Output: 45
```

So to answer your question, no the `ref` keyword does not "copy" the variable.

You can read more about the `ref` keyword here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref