# is there something like C++ const in c#?

Tags: c#, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why const parameters are not allowed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263001/why-const-parameters-are-not-allowed-in-c)

I am a C++ developer and I had some experience using C#.

I have always wondered why there is nothing like this in C#:

```
bool MyFunction(const AnotherClass& x)
{
  //some stuff
}
```

I personally think that the constness is one of the best features in C++ (it helps the developer to increase encapsulation and decoupling). One of the suggestion of Sutter (C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices) is never return your handlers, if I cannot pass by const reference I am giving away the entire class not just the handlers.

Is it my lack of knowledge on C#? There is anything like that in C#? If not, why is C# not using it?

Comment: What does const correctness have to do with either encapsulation or decoupling?

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but isn't that just `bool MyFunction(AnotherClass x)` in C#?

Comment: "Why ..." because C# is a limited language that tries to be simpler at the cost of flexibility and maintainability.

Comment: I can't grasp the ignorance in that statement.

Comment: @ybungalobill - that is FUD; see the linked duplicate for *why*  - in particular, note that it is broken in C/C++. why repeat something that is known to be broken?

Comment: @SWeko: No, that C# is equivilent to `bool MyFunction(AnotherClass& x)` in C++ - there's no way to duplicate const references in C#. The closest you could get would be `bool MyFunction(AnotherStruct x)`

Comment: @Marc Gravell: what do you mean with "broken"? If someone declare a function const and than inside cast away the costness he/she is just a very bad developer. It is not a lack in the functionality. For example, if I throw the wrong exception is the whole exception mechanism broken or just my bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality is not available in C#. You can pass a copy,
you can wrap the object in a read only adapter, or you can pass references to immutable objects/structures.