# How do I assign a readonly member variable in an object initializer?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
class foo {
    public readonly int bar;
};
foo a = new foo() { bar = 123 };
```

`error CS0191: A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)`

How can I assign `bar` in the object initializer above?

**Can I initialize readonly members without having to write a custom constructor for every class/struct ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foo a = new foo() { bar = 123 };
```

is transformed by the compiler to

```
foo temp = new foo();
temp.bar = 123;
foo a = temp;
```

As you can see, the assignment to `bar` is neither in the `foo` constructor nor a variable initializer.

So the answer is: you can't.

Comment: Seems like an oversight from the designers :'(

Comment: @tm1rbrt no, there's no oversight - you should just learn about proper encapsulation

Comment: @scibuff that seems like a safe, single assignment to me?

Comment: @scibuff I'd consider it an oversight and/or bad design.  In this situation the compiler suggests using a variable initializer.  But that's not a solution to the compiler's problem.

Comment: @scibuff In terms of the language design, I'd consider it bad design that C# structs are considered to be only sane in an immutable form (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil), yet the language's variable initializer implementation doesn't work with this.  So struct variable initializers are present in the language, but not a Good Part™ because of the CLI.

Answer (score 8):

To summarize the sentiment of the other answers: *The error message isn't helpful— object initializers can't be used with readonly fields.*

**However, constructors with named arguments can, and the syntax to do so is quite similar.**  So similar you might even be thinking that you've seen C# object initializers for readonly fields *(like I have been)* when what you actually saw was this:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    public readonly int bar;
};

Foo a = new Foo(bar: 123);
// instead of `new Foo() { bar = 123 };`
```

Comment: Exactly! After searching for an hour and reading a lot high voted answers finally the right answer that even makes me understand why I unconsciously just could not believe that initializer lists do not allow assignment to readonly. I still wonder why but named parameters in constructors are just as useful.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the value in on the constructor:

```
public class foo 
{
    public readonly int _bar;

    public foo(int bar) 
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }
};


var x = new foo(12345);
```

What the compiler is telling you is that the only place you can set your readonly field is in the constructor of the class that holds it, this means:

- if you need it to change during the lifetime of the object then `readonly` is not the correct option to use
- if each instance of the class needs to hold a custom value in the readonly member variable then you need to inject it as part of the constructor

I would suggest that it isn't a good practice to make your readonly field *public* like this, instead just expose it as a public property that only has a getter.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
     private int bar;

     public Foo( int bar ){
         this.bar = bar;
     }

     public int Bar {
         get { return this.bar; }
     }
}

Foo foo = new Foo( 123 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You should use the constructor for it.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What the error wants to tell you that you could use

```
class foo {
    public readonly int bar = blabla;
};
```

The object initializer syntax you're using is just syntax sugar for calling the constructor and the assigning to members. And that' not allowed for readonly members.

---

You will need to introduce a constructor parameter, and then assign in the constructor. C# is pretty lacking concerning syntax sugar for immutable types.