# Coming from a C background, what's a good way to implement const reference data tables/structures in C#?

Tags: c#, c

I'll give a quick example of what I'm familiar with implementing using **C**.  The focus I think is on how the data can be used, not so much what I'm doing with it in the example :)

```
typedef struct  
{
  const char  *description;
  uint32_t    colour_id;      
  uint32_t    quantity;
} my_data_t;

const my_data_t ref_data[] =
{
  {"Brown Bear", 0x88,   10},
  {"Blue Horse", 0x666,  42},
  {"Purple Cat", 123456, 50},
};

void show_animals( void )
{
  my_data_t *ptr;

  ptr = &ref_data[2];

  console_write("Animal: %s, Colour: 0x%8X, Num: %d", 
      ptr->description,
      ptr->colour_id,
      ptr->quantity);
}
```

So I'm looking for advice on how similar data tables, or reference data, are implemented in C#.  I'm getting the hang of the higher level side of things, but I haven't dealt with any table driven data methods yet.

As an example, what I might be trying to do in C# is to have a combo box allowing selection from the *description* field, while the *colour id* and *quantity* might be used to update read-only boxes.

That's a really simple example, but if I can determine a good way to implement that, I can extrapolate that to what I'm actually doing.

Comment: If you really come from a C background, you'll see soon that C# is no good... +1 anyways for a good question.

Comment: @H2CO3: discutable comment. Every language has it's appropriate use and place in the world, especilly the languages widely use like `C#`. If you get `F1` super car to drive over golf fields, it will lead to failure. Let's use beautiful tools for appropriate places we have...

Comment: @Tigran That metaphore is worth an upvote.

Comment: @Tigran I agree...  in a lot of ways C allows a good programmer to do some very powerful stuff.  It also allows bad programmers to do some truely horrible things though!  :)

Comment: What I mean, is that with `C#` for 90% cases you can do **much more** stuff then you do in `C` or `C++`, even if you feel your self highly productive in that languages. `.NET` is *extremely* powerful and productive environment, do not understimate it. Sure, I repeat, if you're writing compiler, driver, game, CAD programs, it's better to choose something else, if you can.

Comment: @Tigran You might mean to say that you can do much more with less effort than in C or C++. It's hard to argue that C# is actually more powerful than C or C++, but the .NET framework does allow for people to do more with less work on their part. It's a tool for amplifying work.

Comment: @Takkara: it is *much more powerful* like an environment (.net framework in general), I don't mean a *language* itself, .NET world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) of an immutable class.

```
public class MyData
{
    public MyData(string description, int colorId, int quantity)
    {
        Description = description;
        ColorId = colorId;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }
    public string Description {get; private set; }
    public int ColorId {get; private set; }
    public int Quantity {get; private set; }
}


...

public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<MyData> refData =
    new ReadOnlyCollection<MyData>(
        new [] {
            new MyData("Brown Bear", 0x88,   10),
            new MyData("Blue Horse", 0x666,  42),
            new MyData("Purple Cat", 123456, 50)
            });
```

Comment: +1 for the practical c# approach. You can even use anonymous types for more flexibility.

Comment: Crikey...  Is that really an equivilent sort-of method to dealing with table data?  Thanks, I'll start having a read-up.  A good example of where C let's you handle raw data with less effort  :)

Comment: @Joe Maybe my mention of it being const isn't actually necessary...  I'm accustomed to doing that out of good practice (stores data in flash instead of RAM), but maybe that's not even necessary in C#?  In which case, would I just use Collection?

Comment: why create an array just to call `ToList` on it?  Just use `new List<MyData>` instead of `new []`.

Comment: C# does not provide guarantees of constness the way C does, primarily because C's 'guarantee' isn't one.  Attempting to enforce that idiom upon C# is inevitably going to lead to additional code.  If you _really need_ the table to be unmodifiable, this is the correct approach.  Otherwise, you'd probably be just as well-off using a readonly array in conjunction with an appropriate level of encapsulation.  Note also that this answer adds some code by expanding your data structure into a class,  which is more idiomatic in C#; it is possible to match your original code more closely, if you want.

Comment: @ColeCampbell Hi, do you have a simple example please?

Comment: @Servy - "why create an array just to call ToList on it" - laziness :)

Comment: @Darcy "Maybe my mention of it being const isn't actually necessary" - if you don't need the collection to be readonly ("const"), then you can use an array or a List<T>.

Comment: @Darcy: I have posted an answer which elaborates on my thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
const my_data_t ref_data[] =
{
  {"Brown Bear", 0x88,   10},
  {"Blue Horse", 0x666,  42},
  {"Purple Cat", 123456, 50},
};
```

can be substituted with `readonly` modifier in `C#`, like

```
//INITIALIZED ONES AND NEVER CHANGED, BY CONVENTION
public static readonly ref_data[] my_data_t = new ref_data[] =
{
  new ref_data{Animal = "Brown Bear", Code = 0x88,   Index = 10},
  new ref_data{Animal = "Blue Horse", Code = 0x666,  Index = 42},
  new ref_data{Animal = "Purple Cat", Code = 123456, index = 50},
};
```

where `ref_data` (in this case) is something like

```
public class ref_data
{
   public string Animal {get;set;}
   public int    Code   {get;set;}  //GUESS, PUT APPROPRIATE NAME
   public int    Index  {get;set;}  //GUESS, PUT APPROPRIATE NAME
}
```

The same is valid for constant `const char  *description`, use `readonly`.

I repeat, this is a by convention, as theoretically there is a, by the way, ways to change a data or trick access to it.

There is no concept of **constant pointer** in `C#`, as pointers (in managed memory) constantly moved all arround, as Garbage Collector continuously shrinks (defrags) memory, in order to avoid memory fragmentation, which brings us a benefit of fast allocations.

There is another option too (don't know if this is a suitable in your case or not), you can use *unmanged* access to the code, via `unsafe` modifier and keep all your `C/C++` pointer stuff inside. In this way, you say to Grabage Collector: "wait, I know what I'm doing", so the *all* memory management has to be handled by you (inside **that unmanaged** code) as if you write ordinary `C/C++` code.

Comment: I didn't think C# supported typedef?

Comment: Hi, I don't think that's really answering the question sorry...  I'm interested in how tables of data can be used to drive C# methods, not whether pointers are constant (for example).

Comment: @DarcyWilliams: no there is no no `typedef` and no `#define` (in sence of creating powerful macros). You can use `#define` like conditional compilation dirrective and that's it.

Comment: @DarcyWilliams: What do you mean ? You ask about possible datastructres and I provided them in my answer. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @DarcyWilliams - C# doesn't support `typedef`. You'd need a new structure.

Comment: @Tigran If I can't use typedef how does your example help given that it's using a typedef'd structure?  (my_data_t)  I'm genuinely confused...

Comment: @David  Yep, thanks, that was kind of what I was getting at  :)

Comment: @DarcyWilliams: you need to define a `new` type that contains that type of fields, new class (say)

Comment: @DarcyWilliams - So after you define your new `public struct my_data_t { stuff }`, then you can use the `public static readonly my_data_t[] ref_data` syntax.

Comment: @Tigran Yep, that's what I'm trying to determine...  suggestions please?

Comment: @DarcyWilliams: I edited my answer with more concrete (I hope) example. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer in response to your request that I elaborate on my comment in Joe's answer.

First point:  if you need `my_data_t` to be a struct for whatever reason, C# does support those.  You don't have to upgrade it to a class, as Joe did, unless you want to.

```
public struct MyData
{
    public string Description;
    public uint ColourID;
    public uint Quantity;
}
```

This is a mutable struct.  Given an instance of this struct, I can modify its values if I so choose.  Most people would say that mutable structs are evil.  As a game developer, I would say that mutable structs are *enormously important*, but also *dangerous*.

The mutable fields and properties of any object can be initialized using the object initializer syntax, which is probably most analogous to what you're doing in C:

```
MyData x = { Description = "Brown Bear", ColourID = 0x88, Quantity = 10 };
```

Personally I think this is a bit unwieldy, especially for large structs, but it is available if you want to use it.

You can change the struct to be immutable by adding `readonly` modifiers to its fields:

```
public struct MyData
{
    public MyData(string description, uint colourID, uint quantity)
    {
        this.Description = description;
        this.ColourID = colourID;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }
    public readonly string Description;
    public readonly uint ColourID;
    public readonly uint Quantity;
}
```

Note that `readonly` only prevents the object references from being changed.  It does not prevent the objects themselves from being mutated, if they're mutable.

Note also that I've also added a constructor.  This is because `readonly` fields can *only* be set in a static initializer or inside of the object's constructor (barring some trickery).  Here, you would initialize a new instance of `MyData` as in Joe's answer:

```
MyData x = new MyData("Brown Bear", 0x88, 10);
```

Second point: constness, or the lack thereof.  C# doesn't support C-style constness because C-style constness is *broken*.  Eric Lippert, formerly a developer on the C# language team at Microsoft, elaborated on that point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263001/why-const-parameters-are-not-allowed-in-c-sharp).

It is far better, I think, not to worry about emulating C-style constness unless you really, really, really have a good reason to.  Constness is ultimately a way to prevent your code from being tampered with by the malicious or the ignorant.  The malicious are going to be able to mutate your data whether you like it or not--in C, and in C#--and we have a much better tool for protecting yourself from the ignorance of others: encapsulation!

Wrap the functionality that uses this table inside of a class, make the table a private member of that class, and then *don't mutate it*.  If at some point you *do* need to expose that table to the outside world, *then* you can use `ReadOnlyCollection` as Joe suggested:

```
public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<MyData> ReferenceTable = new ReadOnlyCollection<MyData>(new []
{
    new MyData(/* whatever */),
    new MyData(/* whatever */),
    new MyData(/* whatever */),
});
```

`ReadOnlyCollection` is just a thin wrapper around some other collection, in this case, your data table.  It can wrap any object which implements the `IList<T>` interface, which includes arrays and several of the built-in collections.

One more note: in one of your comments you mentioned that one of the reasons for declaring the table `const` in C is because it influences where the object is allocated in memory.  This is not the case here.  In the example above, `RefData` will be declared on the managed heap, because it's an array, and arrays are reference types.

Comment: Some nitpicking: "ReadOnlyCollection ... can wrap any object which implements the IEnumerable interface" - no, it wraps an IList<T>, there is no constructor that takes an IEnumerable<T>.  Also your "ReferenceTable" property should probably not instantiate a new ReadOnlyCollection each time it's called.

Comment: You're right; my memory failed me.  I updated my answer.  As for your second point, I agree with you, but it's an obvious enough optimization that I didn't want to clutter up my example with it.

Comment: On further consideration, I changed my answer again to reflect your concerns.

Comment: @ColeCampbell Thanks mate, that's very similar to what I ended up implementing...  minus the ReadOnly aspect.  That I realised was more of a left over I'm familiar with using in C to ensure data is loaded from flash rather than copied to RAM.  Thanks