# explicitly mark parameter as mutating in c#

Tags: c#, oop, immutability, mutable

I have a large amount of code that is dependent on a list of objects. the list is modified a lot while being passed around as a parameter to various methods.

Even though *I* understand the workings of this code, I feel uneasy letting such an easy opportunity to make a mistake exist. Is there a way to handle this situation in c# outside of a goofy comment or refactoring?

Comment: Is the list being modified by other threads? Otherwise, what's the problem if the list changes from a method to another?

Comment: I guess it may be a cultural issue based on language background... A function in an ideal world should not modify its parameters. This should be a safely assumable precondition (imo). It isn't being modified in other threads though.

Comment: see Eric's response http://stackoverflow.com/a/3266579/148671

Comment: one dirty way could be to clone the list before sending it as param to method

Comment: Why do you not want to refactor? Seems like it is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I don't think he wants the list to be immutable, or to have a copy of the list in its original state, but just marking explicitly that the list mutates a lot...

Comment: think about `const Type& foo` vs `Type& foo` in C++ and how the absense of `const` is a red-flag that the parameter could be modified. in c# because nothing is ever defined as mutable-immutable it's not immediately clear. I was wondering if the feature did infact exist, though.

Comment: @2c2c: when I started programming in C#, coming from C++, I, too, missed the const modifier a lot :) The bottom line, however, is that in C# there's no such a thing.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to refactor, but what about using `ImmutableList` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Are you mutating the state of the list itself, or the state of the individual items in the list? Is your code performance critical? How memory constrained are you?

Comment: Items are popped off as it passes through different methods. Run run time performance not an issue. Breaking on the other hand would be unfortunate

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing a `List<Something>` around in your code, then it is "mutable" by default, and there is no way to signal this explicitly.

If this is a language background issue (Haskell?), then in C# you should looks things from a different perspective: if you wanted to pass around an immutable collection, you would need to use some different type (maybe an `IEnumerable<Something>`, even if it's not the same as a list); if you're passing around a List, instead, it can be modified by every method that receives it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give that list a special type:

`class MyCustomMutableList : List<int>`

You could even not give it any base class to make sure that any usage site must use this special type in order to be able to access list data.

I would normally consider this a misuse of inheritance. If this is an implementation detail and does not leak out to consumers of your API it's probably good enough. Otherwise, create an `IList<int>` derived class through composition. R# has a feature to delegate all virtual methods to an instance field. That generates all that code.

You also could create a wrapper class that just exposes the required methods to perform the required mutations:

```
class DataCollector {
 public void Add(int item) { ... }
}
```

Since all this object allows to do is mutation it is pretty clear that mutation is going on.