# How to make a class where all fields/properties are const by default?

Tags: c#, constants

it's possible to make a class in C# where all fields and properties are const by default?

- Imaginary example *

`public class foo : const /* or readonly */ 
{
   public int baa = 3;
}`

Comment: What do you mean "by default"?  Do you mean that the type of class requires all members to be constants?

Comment: @SteveDog, I guess he wants them to be const unless specified otherwise.

Comment: [This answer might be useful.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4150512/426894)

Comment: what is the reason you want const by default ?

Comment: It seems you just want every attribute to have some default value which could be altered at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not.

You can make a class static though which forces all members to be static.

Ex:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const int SomeId = 123;
    public const string SomeName = "foo";

    public static readonly DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime();

    public string notConstant = "test"; //does not compile
}
```