# Const correctness in C# with rich types

Tags: c#, .net, constants, const-correctness, readonly

Coming from a C++ background and trying to learn C#, one of the most frustrating language omissions that I've come across is an equivalent to the `const` keyword.

So, I have been attempting to settle on a pattern that I can use to achieve const correctness in C#.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114809/546561) has an interesting suggestion: create a read only interface for all of your types.  But as Matt Cruikshank pointed out in the comments, this becomes problematic if your class has collections or other rich types.  Particularly if you do not have control over the type, and can't make it implement a read-only interface.

Do any patterns or solutions exist that can handle rich types and collections, or are we forced in C# to simply make copies?  Is it better to just give up on const correctness in C# altogether?

Comment: I suggest reading the [Immutability In C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/immutability/) series of blogs by Eric Lippert (the link shows all posts tagged with immutability - look for the ones that are titled with `Immutability in C#`), where immutable collection types are developed.

Comment: If you really want a type to be immutable, you pretty much need to design it as such.  Sure there's `ReadOnlyCollection` and the like, but they're somewhat lackluster in that they still have the mutating methods, they just throw when called.  But yes, I long for a C++-ish `const` reference as well...

Comment: I've been programming C# for years, and I have yet to see a single scenario where the `const` keyword could have saved me from a mistake. The benefits of the `const` in C++ are vastly overstated. Rather than bend over backwards trying to program in C++ using C#, try C#'s model to programming. After a few years, I doubt you'll want to go back.

Comment: @Stargazer712: I'd have to say I disagree on const correctness benefits being overstated.  Sure, it's a pain to do right, but it's worth it in a good design.  That said, I know many who feel the way you do as well, so that's just my $0.02

Comment: Academically, it's worth it. Practically, I have yet to run across a situation where the added effort would've saved any time or money.

Comment: @JeffYates: I'd say it's probably not worth the effort to retrofit a model just for const-correctness, but if you start out with const-correct design from the begining, it can prevent some careless or amateur mistakes.

Comment: @Stargazer712, do you *need* `const`? No, but it definitely gives you some piece of mind, and it allows you to program in ways that would be susceptible to bugs otherwise.  You can feel free to return and pass references rather than copies, knowing that they are safe.  I imagine that the exact argument used against `const` could be used against `private`.  You don't really *need* `private` (blasphemy, I know).  But without it, you have no compile-time assurance of encapsulation.  `const` gives a similar encapsulation by making sure your precious values won't be changed by someone else.

Comment: No doubt. However, aiming for total const-correctness is still often way more expensive than some of the mistakes. There is a definite balance to be had. There is no absolute here. Always being const-correct is just ridiculous. Some designs do not need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you get immutability in C#?  Sure, if you design for it.  You can do creative things with interfaces, and so on, to only expose the `get` of properties and none of the mutable methods.

That said, keep in mind there is nothing that prevents a crafty user from casting it back to the actual type (of course, same could be said of C++, you can cast away const-ness).

```
ISomeReadOnlyInterface readOnly = new SomeFullObject();

// hah, take that read-only interface!
((SomeFullObject)readOnly).SomeMutatingMethod();
```

Same with collections.  Even if you return a ReadOnlyCollection (which prevents mutating behaviors on the collection itself) the data in the collection is still mutable (as long as the type allows it of course).

So I'm afraid there's really no simple answer here.  There's no "flip-a-switch" const that gives you what C++ does.

It's really up to you, you can:

- Design your types to be immutable and return iterators (or other read only sequences) instead of mutable collections.
- Return new copies each time so that if they alter them it's no biggie.
- Just return the actual data and leave tampering behavior as "undefined".
- etc...

The latter is what collections like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` do.  There's nothing that says you can't make the key type a mutable type (but woe if you do), and the MSDN is pretty clear that if you alter the key in such a way that it's hash code changes, it's on your own neck...

For my own work, I tend to keep it simple unless there is actually a big concern my class may be altered in a way that would cause side-effects.  For example, if I'm storing web service results in a cache, I'll return a copy of the cached item instead so that if a user modifies the result they won't inadvertently modify the cached value.

So, long and the short of it is that I wouldn't worry about const-correctness of *every* type you return, that's just way too much.  I'd only worry about things that you return that, if altered, could create a side-effect to other users.

Comment: Great summary, and great advice

Comment: `That said, keep in mind there is nothing that prevents a crafty user from casting it back to the actual type`. This is ridiculous. There is nothing that prevents a user accessing private fields of another object; just use reflection. That doesn't mean that there shouldn't be `private` variables.

Comment: @user I don't think it's ridiculous at all.  The OP was asking if it's possible to make a type `const` and the answer is not a simple one.  Thus it was important to let them know that while that is a simple way to do it, it is not a guarantee.